# filter, aggregate and filter again using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am working on a large table and need to use aggregation quite often. I do most of my data mangling using `dplyr` since the syntax makes much more sense to me. I think Hadley has a very valid point regarding readability of `dplyr` syntax. However, there are parts of the script that requires more efficiency and I am trying to learn `data.table` in the process.

Given the code below, which gives me a portion of the table that excludes rows based on values of `ratio` and `expression` columns (the first 2 filters) then gives the rows that have observations in at least 2 `replicates` aggregated on quadruples, resulting in dimensions 101K x 13.

```
mult.obs <- tidy.dt %>% 
  filter(ratio != "H.L") %>%
  filter(!is.na(expression)) %>%
  group_by(Seq, Gene.names, condition, ratio) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(replicate) > 1)
```

I am having difficulties translating the statement to data.table syntax, my first attempt was:

```
> dt <- tidy.dt[ratio != "H.L" & !is.na(expression), 
+         by = .(Seq, Gene.names, condition, ratio)][
+         uniqueN(replicate > 1)
+         ]

Error in `[.data.table`(tidy.dt, ratio != "H.L" & !is.na(expression),  : 
  'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j
```

which results in an error as you can see.

I have tried the following but it results in a longer and narrower table (141K x 5). Besides the fact that I get more rows (?!) I also don't get all the columns I would like to get.

```
> dt <- tidy.dt[ratio != "H.L" & !is.na(expression), 
+               uniqueN(replicate > 1), 
+               by = .(Seq, Gene.names, condition, ratio)]
```

After checking the data.table documentation for nth time, I know that the `[i,j,by]` syntax roughly corresponds to SQL terms `where, select|update, groupby` and I understand the examples given there but as soon as you venture to new territory getting the `i,j,by` right becomes fairly complicated.

What am I not getting here?

Comment: It's sometimes problematic to use a column name like 'expression'. It's an important R function name. At the very least such practice I liable to result in misleading error messages. Neither of your DT calls make an assignment. The assignment function is ':=' . Multi-step processes may require chaining of '[.data.table'

Comment: @42- that's because I do not want to change the table `tidy.dt`, but to have a filtered copy. I don't need a new column, just to filter based on an aggregate condition.

Comment: You probably know this, but the downvotes are coming from the lack of a [mcve]. Your code is pretty close, just use `if (uniqueN(replicate) > 1L) .SD` in the `j` argument. Hopefully there'll be more natural syntax for this eventually. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788

Comment: @Frank Yes, I realize that people are downvoting because lack of an example, but I find that to be juvenile and over-zealous to be honest. What I am asking here has nothing to do with the actual table, it's about syntax. I believe I made a good effort trying to explain what I am trying to achieve. If anyone thinks the question is unclear or too simple or whatever, they don't have to answer. But zealous down-/close- voting prevents any useful answer to come, which is actively counter productive and rather frustrating.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the answer by the way. I am not entirely sure what the .SD notation is necessary for selecting all rows but it works. If you would be so kind to submit your suggestion as an answer I'd like to upvote and accept that answer.

Comment: You can see details on .SD at `?.SD`. It's a special symbol for an object automatically created in `DT[...]`. Regarding down/closevoting, I figured you were on board with core SO features like MCVEs. I mean, the reasons for them are pretty clear: with clear input and desired output, answerers can verify that what they're doing is correct; future readers can better verify that the issue you're describing is the same problem they're having; and so on. Anyway, I'm fine with leaving it closed and reopening when the `having=` option is added. I've put a link from there to here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `.SD` idiom from data.table. This is used in the `j` argument when using `by` (and can also be used without `by`, but I find it useful mostly with `by`). "SD" means "subset of data" (or something like it). In combination with `by` it contains the data.table for each group.

For example, using the iris dataset:

```
as.data.table(iris)[, .SD[length(unique(Sepal.Length)) == 21], by = Species]
```

Here we are grouping by Species, and then finding groups where there are exactly 21 unique values of Sepal.Length.

So for your problem you might do:

```
tidy.dt[ratio != "H.L" & !is.na(expression),
  .SD[uniqueN(replicate) > 1],
  by = .(Seq, Gene.names, condition, ratio)]
```

Comment: Thanks! 2 quick questions: 1. doesn't `SD` need to be defined somewhere?
 2. Does `.SD[uniqueN(replicate) > 1]` evaluate to `j  = if (uniqueN(replicate) > 1L) .SD` internally or?

Comment: @posdef x[cond] where cond is TRUE or FALSE is the same as if (cond) x. However, if cond is a missing value the "if" version will error out, and if it has a length greater than one, it'll give a warning. I think these are desirable outcomes for debugging, so I always do the "if" way.